# How do I retrieve my lost code after git stash pop with Auto-merging?

Tags: git

I was working on Branch-A. I wanted to checkout Branch-B to test something. So I executed

`git stash`

on Branch-A.

Then I checked out Branch-B and executed `git reset origin Branch-B --hard`.

Later, I forgot I was working on Branch-B and executed `git stash pop` with many message:

```
Auto-merging myfile.h

Auto-merging myfile.cpp
```

I examined `myfile.h/cpp`. My modification lost. How do I retrieve them?

Comment: With git. Do you know your way around command line or what UI are you using? This MAY be an idea start to use a UI - I Find them much simpler to do mass comparisons or research

Comment: `git reflog` may help you

Answer (score 0):

I find out my lost code. Because there are conflicts during the `git stash pop`, so the stashed code didn't really poped up. After I resolved the conflicts, the code emerged.